# How to use ntile without dividing the partition and incrementing each bucket by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking-functions

How can I use the `ntile` ranking function without specifying the number to divide each partition by and instead assign each partition an incrementing number?

I want to group items that have a subset of fields with the same values and then flag them all with the same number such that each group's number increments by one in sorted order.

Comment: Not very clear what are you after,,,,some sample data and desired output will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NTILE` isn't your function.  You want `DENSE_RANK`.

```
select DENSE_RANK() over (Order by Col1, Col2...) GroupFlag,
    * 
from MyTable
```

This would give all records with common values in fields `Col1` and `Col2` the same integer.  The `GroupFlag` integers will start with 1 and count up in the order of the `order by` clause.

Let me know if you intended to ask something else and I'll try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply its exactly what i want but can I do this without change the order of the data @Brian Pressler

Comment: can you please check the previous comment if there is a way to do this.

Comment: You can add an `order by` clause after the `from` clause to order the records in any way that you like... it won't affect the numbering of `GroupFlag`.